# python3 EOFError of input()

Tags: python-3.x

The python 3 code:

```
while True:
    a = []
    s = input()
    if s == '-1':
        break
    else:
        #input
        for x in s.split():
            a.append(int(x))
        #count
        n = len(a)-1
        cnt = 0
        for x in range(n-1):
            for y in range(x+1, n):
                if a[x]+a[x] == a[y] or a[x] == a[y]+a[y]:
                    cnt += 1
        print(cnt)
```

and the input data are:

```
1 4 3 2 22 0
2 4 10 0
5 6 0
-1
```

but under ubuntu 14 it gets error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 3, in <module>
    s = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

why? I've stop the loop when s==-1!

Comment: Well a copy-paste of your code does work at my place (python3.4 on Ubuntu-derived distribution)

Comment: Me neither. Cannot reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An EOFError is raised when a built-in function like `input()` or `raw_input()` do not read any data before encountering the end of their input stream.

The file methods like `read()` return an empty string at the end of the file.
Its happen because when the compiler compile the code it get EOF at end and nothing else to do.

Try using try-except method for this

Answer (score -1):

The `input()` don't read data line by line, but read it all at once. So `s = '1 4 3 2 22 0\n2 4 10 0\n5 6 0\n-1'` in your code, that's why your code didn't stop the loop. If you input `-1` directly, then you can stop the loop.

Comment: `input()` *does* read only one line, cf. [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).